# Is it possible to clear history in windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, command-history

When using CMD, one can press upper arrow key to retrieve old commands.

Is it possible to erase the history of these commands?
If so, how could one do so?

Comment: `Alt-F7` - see [this reference site](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-keyboard.html). Alternatively, you can exit and start `cmd` again.

Comment: @AFH You should make an answer from that comment.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a simple keyboard short-cut, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

There are very few questions on `cmd` that are not answered on [this reference site](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-keyboard.html).

Alternatively, the history is cleared every time you exit and restart `cmd`.

Answer (score 6):

The command `doskey /listsize=0` should do the trick.

Comment: Indeed it does. Interestingly, it has the additional effect of disabling history for the rest of the session (or until the list size is changed again).

Answer (score 0):

Unlike  Linux-based CLIs, In Windows all histories are cleared when you close CMD.

So, don't worry about that.

Comment: Yes I was mostly concerned about that because I remember in Linux I was able to retrieve the commands even after reboot.

Comment: Yeah, However or In addition, you may (again) find useful to reuse commands you have typed for next session. To be able to use them you have to install third party program called [Clink](http://mridgers.github.io/clink/). To use it just click Batch file **clink.bat**  in program folder and to delete histories, delete file **.history** in folder *clink_0.4.8/profile/*  It is smaller program and you can just download it in ZIP because it is portable. _This will be helpful also for other who find it :-))_

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but can you please do us a favor?  You may want to edit your answer so that it includes the suggestion related to Clink.  At the moment, your initial input simply described what had already been said within the officially accepted answer.  Thanks for your help.