# Why does DOSKEY /REINSTALL close Command Prompt?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

I wanted to clear the history of typed command lines,

So I called `DOSKEY /REINSTALL` as explicitly told in the help, but then, my command prompt closed !

Isn't this the right way to clear the history of typed command lines ?

Comment: It may have closed like that because it needed to run as administrator (and so did not run). Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and see how it runs this way.  See the answer in this thread on clearing the history (look down to the second answer) https://superuser.com/questions/1185761/is-it-possible-to-clear-history-in-windows-command-prompt

Comment: Alright, thank you.

Comment: Was my comment an answer for you?

Comment: Yes, it helped me out, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

I suggest visiting this post .: **[Multi-line menu with options selection via DOSKEY](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=34896#p34896)**

***...[doskey handle two buffers, the buffer of the doskey macros, and the buffer of the commands history. Apparently doskey /reinstall not works, it reset any buffer. Also /history show anything even when you see commands with F7...](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5661#p34890)***

---

Just try using:

```bat
%__APPDIR__%doskey.exe /listsize=0 && %__APPDIR__%doskey.exe /listsize=50
```

This will reset your doskey history

```bat
%__APPDIR__%doskey.exe /listsize=0
%__APPDIR__%doskey.exe /listsize=50

rem ::  or...
%__APPDIR__%doskey.exe /listsize=0 && %__APPDIR__%doskey.exe /listsize=50
```

For additional, about your ***prompt closed !...***

Verify if there is some bat/cmd with same name: **`DOSKEY.cmd`** **`DOSKEY.bat`**

```bat
%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r \ doskey.*
```

- Use the full path/name to **`%__APPDIR__%DOSKEY.exe`** instead only **`DOSKEY /REINSTALL`**

```
doskey.exe /reinstall
%__APPDIR__%doskey.exe /listsize=0 && %__APPDIR__%doskey.exe /listsize=50
```

**Obs.:** Try running **`doskey.exe`** (with the full path), from one of the command line outputs below, it may be the **`doskey.exe`** file in **`c:\windows\system32`** maybe corrupted...

```bat
%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r \ doskey.*
```