# Windows Command Line / Batch File Check if 7zip password is correct?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, 7-zip

In a Windows batch file is there a way to check if 7zip password for a zipped file is correct?

I'd like to check if it succeeds, continue with the script (with call or goto routine), and if it does not succeed then state password is not correct then will have it loop back to ask for password again.

I know I can use the test flag `7z t -p%password% <path>` but not sure how to read the result and automate that it's correct or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Conditional Execution/Operators `&&` and `||`:

```all-bat
@echo off 

cd /d "%~dp0" & title <nul & title ..\%~nx0

:Ask_Again
set /p "password= Enter Passowrd: "

"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" t -p%password% Q1543606.7z >nul 2>nul && (
  echo/Your Password input: zOk! & goto :Next
  ) || set Password=<nul && goto :Ask_Again

:Next
rem :: So, continue...
rem :: Do more here...
Goto :Eof
```

---

---

You can also use some additional answers/codes if you're using it on Windows 10, and taking advantage of **ANSI Escape Code** support to mask/hide the input type for password...

- For mask an input in a bat, you can use the solution from **[@Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini)** in this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24792070/8177207)**
- To delete/remove used lines where the user has entered the password, you can use the solution from **[@LotPings](https://superuser.com/users/639112/lotpings)** in this **[answer](https://superuser.com/a/1476789/969781)**
- For to clear the history of typed command lines (remove the password too), from `Doskey` buffers/history, thus preventing from appearing when pressing keys (arrows, F1, F3 etc...), you can use the solution from **[@It Wasn't Me](https://superuser.com/users/969781/it-wasnt-me)** in this **[answer](https://superuser.com/a/1525738/969781)**

The next code intends to show how to use the options of the answers mentioned above together in a single file/execution for to answer your question.

```all-bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd/d "%~dp0" & color 0a & title <nul && title ..\%~nx0
set "_full_7z_path=F:\SUPER_USER\Q1543606\Q1543606.7z"
"%__APPDIR__%Certutil.exe" -decode -f "%~f0" "%temp%\2L.bin" >nul 2>&1 & goto :Ask_Again
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----  G1sxRhtbMEobWzFGG1swSg0K  -----END CERTIFICATE-----

:Ask_Again
set /p "=_" < nul > "Enter password"
findstr /A:1E /V "^$" "Enter password" nul >con
del "Enter password" && set /P "password="
color 0a & type "%temp%\2l.bin"

%__APPDIR__%doskey.exe /reinstall
%__APPDIR__%doskey.exe /listsize=0
%__APPDIR__%doskey.exe /listsize=50

"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" t -p!password! "%_full_7z_path%" >nul 2>&1  && (
  echo/Your Password input: zOk^!! & goto :Next
  ) || set Password=<nul & goto :Ask_Again

:Next
rem :: So, continue...
rem :: Do more here...
del /q /f "%temp%\2l.bin"
set password=<nul && endlocal && goto :Eof
```

- Below you can see the results/outputs:

[image]

**Obs.:** Remember that it may be necessary to escape if your password contains any special characters, also put the full path to `file.7z` and `7z.exe` respectively....

- About the strings in Base64 in this bat/cmd decoded in file "`%temp%\2l.bin`

[image]

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Doskey](https://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html)**

  [√] **[Findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**

  [√] **[Goto :Label](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.htm)**

  [√] **[Escape Characters](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

  [√] **[Ansi Escape Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)**

  [√] **[Base64 Encode or Decode (MacOS/Windows/Linux)](https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2017/04/26/base64-encode-or-decode-on-the-command-line-without-installing-extra-tools-on-linux-windows-or-macos/)**

Comment: Thank you so much for that detailed response! So if I understand right, it will execute && command if no error and || will execute command if error?

Comment: @HTWingNut yEp, exec && return 0 || return /not(0) see linked Conditional Execution || &&...